# Spring Tool Suite/Gradle/MapStruct - Cannot find implementation for mapper

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, classnotfoundexception, mapstruct

I have searched StackOverflow for an answer to my question. While I have found many offered solutions, none work in my situation.

I have to use MapStruct for a project at work, so I am trying to learn it through [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mapstruct/mapstruct_basic_mapping.htm). However, instead of using Maven as the tutorial suggests, I am using Gradle, which I have to do because my company uses Gradle instead of Maven. I have seen answers in StackOverflow that moving the project to Maven gets it to work, but that is not an option in my case.

I am using version 1.4.2.Final instead of 1.5.0.RC1 because I had a different issue when using the latter that resolved by switching to the former.

Here are the parts of my code:

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.tutorialspoint'
version = '2.4.2'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation group: 'org.mapstruct', name: 'mapstruct', version: '1.4.2.Final'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final"
    compileOnly 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += [
        '-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp=true',
        '-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorVersionInfoComment=true',
        '-Amapstruct.verbose=true'
    ]
}
```

Student.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint.mapstructproject;

public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String className;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return className;
    }

    public void setClassName(String className) {
        this.className = className;
    }
}
```

StudentEntity.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint.mapstructproject;

public class StudentEntity {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String classVal;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getClassVal() {
        return classVal;
    }

    public void setClassVal(String classVal) {
        this.classVal = classVal;
    }
}
```

StudentMapper.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint.mapstructproject;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;

@Mapper(componentModel="spring")
public interface StudentMapper {
    @Mapping(target="className", source="classVal")
    Student getModelFromEntity(StudentEntity student);

    @Mapping(target="classVal", source="className")
    StudentEntity getEntityFromModel(Student student);
}
```

StudentMapperTest.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint.mapstructproject;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;
import com.tutorialspoint.mapstructproject.StudentEntity;
import com.tutorialspoint.mapstructproject.StudentMapper;
import com.tutorialspoint.mapstructproject.Student;

public class StudentMapperTest {
    private StudentMapper studentMapper = Mappers.getMapper(StudentMapper.class);

    @Test
    public void testEntityToModel() {
        StudentEntity entity = new StudentEntity();
        entity.setClassVal("X");
        entity.setName("John");
        entity.setId(1);
        Student model = studentMapper.getModelFromEntity(entity);
        assertEquals(entity.getClassVal(), model.getClassName());
        assertEquals(entity.getName(), model.getName());
        assertEquals(entity.getId(), model.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void testModelToEntity() {
        Student model = new Student();
        model.setId(1);
        model.setName("John");
        model.setClassName("X");
        StudentEntity entity = studentMapper.getEntityFromModel(model);
        assertEquals(entity.getClassVal(), model.getClassName());
        assertEquals(entity.getName(), model.getName());
        assertEquals(entity.getId(), model.getId());
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for com.tutorialspoint.mapstructproject.StudentMapper
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:61)
    at com.tutorialspoint.mapstructproject.StudentMapperTest.<init>(StudentMapperTest.java:11)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:550)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConstructorInvocation.proceed(ConstructorInvocation.java:56)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestClassConstructor(InvocationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:302)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:280)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for com.tutorialspoint.mapstructproject.StudentMapper
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:75)
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:58)
    ... 68 more
```

UPDATE: Someone asked about the build file. I don't see a build file in my project, probably because the build never succeeds due to the error. Here is my file structure:
[image]

Comment: No idea if this helps, but I only have these 2 mapstruct dependency lines when working with gradle. `implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'` and `annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'`.
Also can you check if the generated implementation classes are generated in the build folder.

Comment: @BenZegveld I started with only those two dependency lines and added the others in an attempt to solve the problem. As to checking if the generated implementation, I don't have a build file. I will edit the question to show the folder and file structure of the project.

Comment: What are you using to run the build/tests? `./gradlew build`? or an IDE?

Comment: @BenZegveld I'm using Spring Tool Suite to run the builds and the tests.

Comment: did you do the eclipse (STS is based on eclipse) configuration mentioned here? https://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/

Comment: Please add the solution if you found

Answer (score 1):

For me works:

```
implementation group: 'org.mapstruct', name: 'mapstruct', version: '1.5.3.Final'
implementation group: 'org.mapstruct', name: 'mapstruct-processor', version: '1.5.3.Final'
compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.24'


annotationProcessor group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.24'
annotationProcessor group: 'org.mapstruct', name: 'mapstruct-processor', version: '1.5.3.Final'
```

Taken from https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/main/mapstruct-lombok/build.gradle

Optionally works **without** (*please `confirm` it*):

```
annotationProcessor group: 'org.mapstruct', name: 'mapstruct-processor', version: '1.5.3.Final'
```