# @SpringBootTest context does not load because it cannot find @Autowired Mapstruct @Mapper components

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, junit, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple RESTful API built with Spring Boot that works perfectly when testing manually at start up. In fact, it also works well when conducting unit tests. However, I'm unfortunately able to get the context to load properly for `@SpringBootTest` and it says that it cannot find components that should be autowired. I've spend a couple days looking at this, attempting different configurations and tutorials online but nothing has worked thus far. I'm hoping someone else might have a tip to help me.

[Here is a sample project to try booting up to reproduce.](https://github.com/BillyBolton/DCMS-tested/tree/billy)

To boot up, run `./gradlew api:bootRun`. You can explore the functionality by reaching `localhost:8080/api-docs/swagger-ui`. (Note: I am specifically interested in the api sub-module). The test in question can be found along the relative path: [`./api/src/test/java/ca/me/proj/api/ApiApplicationTests.java`](https://github.com/BillyBolton/DCMS-tested/tree/billy)

```java
    package ca.me.proj.api;
    
    import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Disabled;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
    import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
    import ca.me.proj.api.config.TestWebConfig;
    
    // @Disabled("Autowired components not being scanned properly.")
    @SpringBootTest
    class ApiApplicationTests {
    
        @Test
        void contextLoads() {
            assertTrue(true);
        }
    
    
    }
```

The error I get is:

```bash
    2022-06-02 10:34:50.342 DEBUG 985 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : Application failed to start due to an exception

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ca.me.proj.api.mapper.base.IBaseMapper<ca.me.proj.api.dtos.address.AddressDTO, ca.me.proj.api.entity.address.AddressEntity>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

...

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method setService in ca.me.proj.api.service.base.AbstractBaseServiceImpl required a bean of type 'ca.me.proj.api.mapper.base.IBaseMapper' that could not be found.
2

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'ca.me.proj.api.mapper.base.IBaseMapper' in your configuration.

2022-06-02 10:34:50.345 ERROR 985 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@a43ce46] to prepare test instance [ca.me.proj.api.ApiApplicationTests@37ddb69a]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132


...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ca.me.proj.api.mapper.base.IBaseMapper<ca.me.proj.api.dtos.address.AddressDTO, ca.me.proj.api.entity.address.AddressEntity>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:759
    ... 102 common frames omitted
```

**Other files of interests that might help:**

- [Gradle file for sub-module](https://github.com/BillyBolton/DCMS-tested/blob/billy/api/build.gradle)

```
    plugins {
      id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.6'
      id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
      id 'java'
      id "org.sonarqube" version "3.3"
      id 'java-library' //important for QDSL
      id 'jacoco'
      id 'war' //important for QDSL
    }
     
    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
     
    // pulls out properties from a global properties file
    Properties env = new Properties()
    File subPropertiesFile = new File("$projectDir/env.properties")
    subPropertiesFile.withInputStream {
      env.load(it)
    }
     
    // define environment and application settings
    def applicationName = env.APPLICATION_NAME
    def buildNumber = env.APPLICATION_BUILD_VERSION
    group = env.APPLICATION_GROUP
    version = env.APPLICATION_VERSION
    def archiveClassifierName = env.ARCHIVE_CLASSIFIER
    def javaVersion = JavaVersion.toVersion(env.JAVA_VERSION)
    sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
    targetCompatibility = javaVersion
    compileJava.options.encoding = env.ENCODING
     
    def archiveName = "${applicationName}##${version}.${buildNumber}"
     
    def profiles = (project.hasProperty('profiles')
      ? project.property('profiles')
      : env.DEFAULT_LOCAL_SPRING_PROFILES).split(",");
     
    // configure tasks
    bootRun {
      args = ["--spring.profiles.active=${profiles.join(",")}"]
    }
     
    bootJar {
      archiveFileName = "${archiveName}.jar"
    }
     
    bootWar {
      archiveFileName = "${archiveName}.war"
    }
     
    test {
      useJUnitPlatform()
     
      // need to be able to pass through the active profile supplied in gradle task
      systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', profiles.join(",")
      testLogging {
                      outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
                      showStandardStreams = true
      }
     
    }
     
    jacocoTestReport {
        reports {
            xml.enabled true
        }
    }
    test.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
     
    sonarqube {
        properties {
            def props = new Properties()
            file("sonar-project.properties").withInputStream { props.load(it)}
            props.each {
              property("${it.key}", "${it.value}")
            }
        }
    }
     
    tasks.named('sonarqube').configure {
        dependsOn test
    }
     
    configurations {
      developmentOnly
      compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
      }
    }
     
    ext {
      DB_DRIVER_VERSION = "42.2.18"
      GSON_VERSION = "2.8.5" // for JSON support
      H2_VERSION = "1.4.+"
      JUNIT_VERSION = "5.3.1"
      VALIDATION_VERSION = "7.0.1.FINAL"
      MAPSTRUCT_VERSION = '1.4.1.Final'
      MAPSTRUCT_BINDING_VERSION = '0.2.0'
      MOCKITO_VERSION = '2.18.3'
      QDSL_VERSION = '5.0.0'
      SPRINGDOC_VERSION='1.5.10'
      RESTASSURED_VERSION = '4.1.2'
      XML_VERSION='4.+'
      QUERYDSL_VERSION = '5.0.0'
    }
     
    compileJava {
        options.compilerArgs += [
            '-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring'
        ]
    }
     
    sourceSets {
        generated {
            java {
                srcDirs += ["$projectDir/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main"]
            }
        }
    }
     
     
     
    dependencies {
    
     
         runtimeOnly "org.postgresql:postgresql:$DB_DRIVER_VERSION"
      // else {
     
      //   // if (profiles.contains("tc")) {
      //   if (false) {
      //   implementation "org.postgresql:postgresql:$DB_DRIVER_VERSION"
     
      //     implementation "org.testcontainers:postgresql:$TESTCONTAINERS_VERSION"
      //     runtimeOnly "org.testcontainers:testcontainers:$TESTCONTAINERS_VERSION"
      //     testCompile "org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:$TESTCONTAINERS_VERSION"
      //   }
      // } 
     
      annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
     
     
      // annotations for getters/setters/ctors/equals/hashCode
      annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok"
      testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok"
      implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok"
      testImplementation "org.projectlombok:lombok"
     
      // easier/faster DTOs
      annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:$MAPSTRUCT_VERSION"
      testAnnotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:$MAPSTRUCT_VERSION"
      implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:$MAPSTRUCT_VERSION"
      testImplementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:$MAPSTRUCT_VERSION"
     
     
     
      // required for binding mapstruct and lombok together
      annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:$MAPSTRUCT_BINDING_VERSION"
      testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:$MAPSTRUCT_BINDING_VERSION"
     
      // better dev experience in bootRun
      developmentOnly "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools"
     
      // work with XML
      annotationProcessor "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:$XML_VERSION"
      implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml"
     
      // health checks
      implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
     
      // persistance and validation with hibernate
      implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
        annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" // Needed for Qdsl
      // implementation "org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:$VALIDATION_VERSION"
      // implementation "javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final"
      annotationProcessor "javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final"
      // implementation "org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.0"
      annotationProcessor "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api"
     
      // protects API calls using oauth2 access tokens
      // implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server"
      // implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.6.1'
     
     
      // standard MVC architecture
      implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
     
      // set to 'providedRuntime' to allow both jar/war deploys
      providedRuntime "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
     
      // easier mocks
      testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:$MOCKITO_VERSION"
     
      // easier REST testing
      testImplementation "io.rest-assured:rest-assured-all:$RESTASSURED_VERSION"
      testImplementation "io.rest-assured:spring-mock-mvc:3.3.0"
     
      // allows for SpringBootTest
      testImplementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
     
      // Spring and Azure Active Directory
      // compile "com.azure.spring:azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory:3.6.1"
     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.6.1'
     
      // API documentation
     
      implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:$SPRINGDOC_VERSION"
      implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-data-rest:$SPRINGDOC_VERSION"
      // implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-security:$SPRINGDOC_VERSION"
     
     
     
      // Better Queries
      // api "com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:$QDSL_VERSION"
      // annotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:$QDSL_VERSION:jpa"
      // implementation "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:$QDSL_VERSION:jpa"
      // compile "com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:$QDSL_VERSION"
      annotationProcessor "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api"
      testAnnotationProcessor "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api"
      // implementation "com.querydsl:querydsl-core:$QDSL_VERSION"
     
      implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$GSON_VERSION"
     
      implementation 'javax.interceptor:javax.interceptor-api:1.2.2'
      testImplementation 'javax.interceptor:javax.interceptor-api:1.2.2'
     
     
    }
     
    // make sure your environment is set up correctly!
    task checkEnvironment {
      doFirst {
        if(JavaVersion.current() != javaVersion) {
          throw new IOException("Configured version of Java (${javaVersion}) is different than the host version (${JavaVersion.current()})")
        }
     
        println "Spring Boot profiles: ${profiles}"
        println "Java: ${javaVersion} (${env.JAVA_VERSION})"
      }
    }
     
    compileJava.dependsOn checkEnvironment
```

- Controllers
- [Abstract Controller](https://github.com/BillyBolton/DCMS-tested/blob/billy/api/src/main/java/ca/me/proj/api/controller/base/AbstractCrudController.java)

```java
    package ca.me.proj.api.controller.base;
    
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import ca.me.proj.api.constants.ApiUri;
    import ca.me.proj.api.dtos.base.BaseDTO;
    import ca.me.proj.api.entity.base.AbstractBaseEntity;
    
    public abstract class AbstractCrudController<D extends BaseDTO, E extends AbstractBaseEntity, PK>
            extends AbstractReadController<D, E, PK> {
    
        @PostMapping(ApiUri.SAVE)
        public D save(@RequestBody D dto) {
            return service.save(dto);
        }
    
        @PutMapping(ApiUri.SAVE)
        public D update(@RequestBody D dto) {
            return service.update(dto);
        }
    
        @DeleteMapping(ApiUri.DELETE)
        public boolean deleteById(@RequestParam PK id) {
            return service.deleteById(id);
        }
    
    }
```

- [Concrete Controller Example](https://github.com/BillyBolton/DCMS-tested/blob/billy/api/src/main/java/ca/me/proj/api/controller/address/AddressController.java)

```java
    package ca.me.proj.api.controller.address;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import ca.me.proj.api.controller.base.AbstractCrudController;
    import ca.me.proj.api.dtos.address.AddressDTO;
    import ca.me.proj.api.entity.address.AddressEntity;
    import ca.me.proj.api.service.address.AddressService;
    
    
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/address")
    public class AddressController extends AbstractCrudController<AddressDTO, AddressEntity, String> {
    
        @Autowired
        private AddressService addressService;
    
        @PostMapping("/findBy/address")
        public AddressDTO findByAddress(@RequestBody AddressDTO dto) {
            return addressService.findByAddress(dto);
        }
    }
```

- Service
- [Abstract Service](https://github.com/BillyBolton/DCMS-tested/blob/billy/api/src/main/java/ca/me/proj/api/service/base/AbstractBaseServiceImpl.java)

```java
    package ca.me.proj.api.service.base;
    
    import java.util.List;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import ca.me.proj.api.dtos.base.BaseDTO;
    import ca.me.proj.api.dtos.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException;
    import ca.me.proj.api.entity.base.AbstractBaseEntity;
    import ca.me.proj.api.mapper.base.IBaseMapper;
    import ca.me.proj.api.repository.base.IBaseRepository;
    
    public abstract class AbstractBaseServiceImpl<D extends BaseDTO, E extends AbstractBaseEntity, PK>
            implements IBaseService<D, PK> {
    
    
        protected IBaseMapper<D, E> mapper;
        protected IBaseRepository<E, PK> repository;
    
        @Autowired
        public void setService(IBaseMapper<D, E> mapper, IBaseRepository<E, PK> repository) {
            this.mapper = mapper;
            this.repository = repository;
        }
    
    
        public boolean existsById(PK id) {
            return repository.existsById(id);
        }
    
    
        public List<D> findAll() {
            return mapper.entityToDto(repository.findAll());
        }
    
        public D findById(PK id) {
            if (!existsById(id)) {
                throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Entity with id: " + id + " not found");
            }
            return mapper.entityToDto(repository.findById(id).orElse(null));
        }
    
        public D save(D dto) {
            return mapper.entityToDto(repository.save(mapper.dtoToEntity(dto)));
        }
    
        public List<D> save(Iterable<D> dto) {
            return mapper.entityToDto(repository.saveAll(mapper.dtoToEntity(dto)));
        }
    
        public D update(D dto) {
            // TODO: validation checks
            return this.save(dto);
        }
    
        public List<D> update(Iterable<D> dtos) {
            // TODO: validation checks
            return mapper.entityToDto(repository.saveAll(mapper.dtoToEntity(dtos)));
        }
    
        public boolean deleteById(PK id) {
    
            if (!existsById(id)) {
                throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Resource not found with id " + id);
            }
    
            repository.deleteById(id);
            boolean deleteSuccessful = !repository.existsById(id);
            return deleteSuccessful;
        }
    
    }
```

- [Concrete Service Example](https://github.com/BillyBolton/DCMS-tested/blob/billy/api/src/main/java/ca/me/proj/api/service/address/AddressService.java)

```java
    package ca.me.proj.api.service.address;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import ca.me.proj.api.dtos.address.AddressDTO;
    import ca.me.proj.api.dtos.exceptions.ResourceAlreadyExistsException;
    import ca.me.proj.api.dtos.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException;
    import ca.me.proj.api.entity.address.AddressEntity;
    import ca.me.proj.api.mapper.address.IAddressMapper;
    import ca.me.proj.api.repository.address.IAddressRepository;
    import ca.me.proj.api.service.base.AbstractBaseServiceImpl;
    
    @Service
    public class AddressService extends AbstractBaseServiceImpl<AddressDTO, AddressEntity, String> {
    
        @Autowired
        private IAddressMapper mapper;
    
    
    
        @Autowired
        private IAddressRepository addressRepository;
    
        public AddressDTO findByAddress(AddressDTO dto) {
            if (!existsByAddress(dto)) {
                throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Address: " + dto + " not found");
            }
            return mapper.entityToDto(
                    addressRepository.findByBuildingNumberAndStreetAndCityAndProvinceAndPostalCode(
                            dto.getBuildingNumber(), dto.getStreet(), dto.getCity(), dto.getProvince(),
                            dto.getPostalCode()));
        }
    
        public AddressDTO create(AddressDTO dto) {
            checkExists(dto);
            return save(dto);
        }
    
        public void checkExists(AddressDTO dto) {
            if (dto.getId() != null && repository.existsById(dto.getId())) {
                throw new ResourceAlreadyExistsException("Address ID already exists");
            }
    
            if (existsByAddress(dto)) {
                throw new ResourceAlreadyExistsException("Address already exists");
            }
        }
    
        public boolean existsByAddress(AddressDTO dto) {
            return addressRepository.existsByBuildingNumberAndStreetAndCityAndProvinceAndPostalCode(
                    dto.getBuildingNumber(), dto.getStreet(), dto.getCity(), dto.getProvince(),
                    dto.getPostalCode());
        }
    
    
    }
```

- Mapper
- [Generic Mapper](https://github.com/BillyBolton/DCMS-tested/blob/billy/api/src/main/java/ca/me/proj/api/mapper/base/IBaseMapper.java)

```java
    package ca.me.proj.api.mapper.base;
    
    import java.util.List;
    import ca.me.proj.api.dtos.base.BaseDTO;
    import ca.me.proj.api.entity.base.AbstractBaseEntity;
    
    public interface IBaseMapper<D extends BaseDTO, E extends AbstractBaseEntity> {
    
        D entityToDto(E entity);
    
        E dtoToEntity(D dto);
    
        List<E> dtoToEntity(Iterable<D> dtos);
    
        List<D> entityToDto(Iterable<E> entities);
    
    }
```

- [Concrete Mapper Example](https://github.com/BillyBolton/DCMS-tested/blob/billy/api/src/main/java/ca/me/proj/api/mapper/address/IAddressMapper.java)

```java
    package ca.me.proj.api.mapper.address;
    
    import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
    import ca.me.proj.api.dtos.address.AddressDTO;
    import ca.me.proj.api.entity.address.AddressEntity;
    import ca.me.proj.api.mapper.base.IBaseMapper;
    
    @Mapper
    public interface IAddressMapper extends IBaseMapper<AddressDTO, AddressEntity> {
    
    }
```

- Repository
- [NoRepository Interface](https://github.com/BillyBolton/DCMS-tested/blob/billy/api/src/main/java/ca/me/proj/api/repository/base/IBaseRepository.java)

```
    package ca.me.proj.api.repository.base;
    
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
    
    @NoRepositoryBean
    public interface IBaseRepository<E, PK> extends JpaRepository<E, PK> {
    
    }
```

- [Repository Example](https://github.com/BillyBolton/DCMS-tested/blob/billy/api/src/main/java/ca/me/proj/api/repository/address/IAddressRepository.java)

```
    package ca.me.proj.api.repository.address;
    
    import javax.transaction.Transactional;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import ca.me.proj.api.constants.province.Province;
    import ca.me.proj.api.entity.address.AddressEntity;
    import ca.me.proj.api.repository.base.IBaseRepository;
    
    @Transactional
    @Repository
    public interface IAddressRepository extends IBaseRepository<AddressEntity, String> {
    
            public AddressEntity findByBuildingNumberAndStreetAndCityAndProvinceAndPostalCode(
                            long buildingNumber, String street, String city, Province province,
                            String postalCode);
    
            public boolean existsByBuildingNumberAndStreetAndCityAndProvinceAndPostalCode(
                            long buildingNumber, String street, String city, Province province,
                            String postalCode);
    
    }
```

Any help would be a life saver!

Comment: I think would be related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/71651101/811293